# Problems in reading date column of SQL Server in Python using pymssql package

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, odbc, pymssql

I have a date column (trnDate) in an SQL Server Table, which is stored like this in DB

---

2021-11-29 09:48:05.0000000 +04:00

---

To read this in Jupyter Notebook, I am using the pymssql package. My code looks like this below

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "HecPoll5")
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from dbo.v_beeah_data where customerid=379691', conn )
print(df)
```

The result set however gives me the output where i get hex characters in my dates (marked in bold).

TID----Number----trnDate----LiveMandatorID----Quantity----CustomerID 
63221----731----****b'\x00$\xd5\xffB\x00\x00\x00\xbc\xae\x00\x00\x...****----1----80.0----379691

I have tried adding

parse_dates={"trnDate":"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"} &
parse_dates=True in **read_sql_query** & adding charset="UTF-8" parameters in **connect** as well, nothing have so far worked well.

This is the first time I am using this library, all other columns in the result set works well except the date column. If anyone has previously encountered such issue, kindly help with what I am missing here.

Comment: the return is a bytes string, so this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: and this to convert the bytes data to a string:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string